# why spark internally uses batch writes to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am new to spark , i am trying to understand  Why does spark writes in batches to Cassandra (eg: savetocassandra operation) , when batches are not so efficient for all uses cases. What should be really taken care off from cassandra side or spark side , when we are doing spark job which reads from cassandra and writes back to cassandra , apart from optimizing the spark.cassandra properties.

Is it logged batched write or unlogged batch write ?

Comment: The spark-cassandra connector uses unlogged batches.

Comment: It turns out unlogged batches are more performant than async queries for the kinds of operations that spark jobs tend to perform.

Comment: thanks that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very specific to Spark to Cassandra , but any process writing to service

1. Spark writes to cassandra via API and not as file
2. Batch always speed up the puts as in one API call you batch multiple rows to be put.
3. Batching leads to difficult handling of exactly one semantics .
4. You can always write your own Spark task to do one put at a time.
5. I think single vs batch should be configurable

Answer (score 2):

Here is the the great explanation:
Maximum Overdrive: Tuning the Spark Cassandra Connector (Russell Spitzer, DataStax) | C* Summit 2016
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKIHRD6kUOc